# TJvAppXMLFileStorage OnGetFileName event never executed

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, jvcl

In Delphi 10 Seattle, with JVCL 3.48, after having implemented `TJvAppXMLFileStorage` `OnGetFileName` event handler, it never gets executed:

```
procedure TForm1.JvAppXMLFileStorage1GetFileName(Sender:
    TJvCustomAppStorage; var FileName: TFileName);
begin
  // never gets executed!
  CodeSite.Send('JvAppXMLFileStorage1GetFileName', FileName.ToString);
end;
```

I need this event to set the `JvAppXMLFileStorage1.Location` property with the `var FileName` parameter depending from other settings.

So how can I get this event executed?

Comment: From what I can see in `JvAppStorage.pas`, `OnGetFileName` is only dispatched if `Location` is set to `flCustom` (see `procedure TJvCustomAppMemoryFileStorage.RecalculateFullFileName;`).

Comment: Sorry (phone call) - edit limed out.. `RecalculateFullFileName` only calls `DoGetFileName` in the `case Location of` branch for `flCustom`.

Comment: JEDI has no real documentation so you have to read the source

Comment: @KenWhite Many thanks, please create an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This is really sad, as JEDI is a great library with an enormous potential. I wonder why Embarcadero does not maintain it (while keeping it open source of course). In the long term it would be a profit for Embarcadero.

Comment: Why would it be beneficial for Emba to do that? They'd need to pay more developer and doc authors. Would they increase revenue? I doubt by very much.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In the long-term they would increase revenue. It is odd that today everybody seems to think short-term - don't know why...

Comment: Why would they increase revenue? I don't see why that would happen. And they need to increase it by more than the cost. And the JEDI people have to agree. Perhaps they would not. Buying up lots of third party libraries as Emba have done recently, and charging more for them than before, does tend to upset the community.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan A student sees Delphi with a huge JEDI library which is very well maintained and very well documented. So he thinks: Wow, this is cool! Let's stick with this development environment! Later he buys Delphi Enterprise and Embarcadero sells many Delphi licenses.

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. I personally don't agree in the case of this library, but the principle is sound enough. I'm not convinced that JEDI is that great a library. It is very large, and has far more interdependencies that is desirable. Bear in mind that Emba have just bought Raize components, a library whose quality and breadth is renowned.

Comment: Raize components are very expensive. Student thinks: I need to buy food, don't have money for Raize components. Then he chooses another development environment. Then Embarcadero sells no licenses to the student who later has become a successful developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick look at *JvAppStorage.pas* seems to show that the only place that calls `DoGetFileName` (which is where `OnGetFileName` is triggered if there is one assigned) is in `TJvCustomAppMemoryFileStorage.RecalculateFullFileName`. Looking at that method, `DoGetFileName` is only called from the `case Location of` branch for `flCustom`.

This seems to indicate that the event is only fired if it's assigned *and* the `Location` is `flCustom`.